# is there any open data for traffic information which is contain road intersection, traffic route, traffic speed, traffic volume?

Tags: dictionary, dataset, traffic, opendata

i knew several open data for traffic such as cityofchicago, socrata, pems, RDE
but hardly i found dataset with contains road intersection, traffic route, traffic speed, traffic volume (count of vehicles).
i would appreciate for all of you could help me please.
need guidance.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Chicago, but have you come across this dataset: [Chicago Traffic Tracker - Congestion Estimates by Regions | City of Chicago | Data Portal](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/Chicago-Traffic-Tracker-Congestion-Estimates-by-Re/t2qc-9pjd)

Chicago actually has a bunch of [traffic-related datasets](https://data.cityofchicago.org/browse?limitTo=datasets&q=traffic&sortBy=relevance) posted.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly off-topic. It encourages future questions that are not appropriate, because the user decides they can get an answer anyway. Questions asking us to find or recommend anything are off-topic, as clearly stated in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: i also need intersection information, how many vehicle turn left, turn right, go straight, something like that..